# bash script is not waiting for user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm wrote small bash shell script named hello.sh, that will ask the user to enter his name and again prints the user entered name.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your name : "
read uname
echo "Hello " $uname ", Welcome to shell scripting."
```

when I run the script, `./hello.sh` it won't wait for user input and gives me the below output

```
./hello.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
': not a valid identifiere 3: read: `uname
Hello  , Welcome to shell scripting.
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Your script has DOS CRLF endings. Run `dos2unix hello.sh` and rerun your script

Comment: when I run dos2unix hello.sh, saying 
dos2unix hello.sh
dos2unix: Failed to change the permissions of temporary output file ./d2utmpKyz65o: Operation not permitted
dos2unix: problems converting file hello.sh